# Does jquery.flot.dashes.js support plothover and plotclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, flot

I have a workable tooltip system set-up with my normal graphing options (not using dashes) by using the plothover event, but the plot is not hoverable when I switch to my "black and  white" mode (using dashes). Is there any way to keep the graph hoverable and clickable when using dashes? Or a way to make a decent looking plot in black and white without dashes?

Example series: `{data: data, dashes:{show: true, dashLength: 2}, color: "black", label: "Series 1"}`

My current graphing options:

```
options = {
      yaxis: {max: maxValue, min: minValue},
      grid: {hoverable: true, clickable: true},
      legend: {show: false},
      xaxis: {tickFormatter: null}
  };
```

I use plothover event for tooltips like this:

`$(this).bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item){
   //tooltip code here
}`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Define "decent looking plot in black and white". You can change the colors flot uses, either per series or globally.

Comment: By "decent looking plot in black and white," I mean is there a way that I can make a black and white plot that you can distinguish multiple series from each other without using jquery.flot.dashes.js? I'll post pictures of color mode and black and white (dashed) mode.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vX2G/2/) using different shades of grey. Note that I did specify the colors globally. If there are more data series than colors, flot will generated additional colors by varying the defined colors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=61#c44) filled against the `jQuery.flot.dashes` plugin.

> Regarding the hover issue, there's a function called "findNearbyItem"
>   in jquery.flot.js that performs the search only if the plot is showing
>   lines, points or bars. If you only have "dashes" showing, then it
>   won't perform the search.
>
> Two choices:
>   - Modify the jquery.flot.js file in the following line: `if (s.lines.show || s.points.show)`  to something like
>       `if (s.lines.show || s.points.show || s.dashes.show)`
>   - Show points with 0 radius in the series you show dashes: (from the example in comment #41)
>   `{ label: "sin(x)",  data: d1, dashes: { show: true, steps:true }, points: {show: true, radius:0 }}`

I agree with the poster that the second solution is a better idea.  I've also tried it out [in this fiddle and is works well](http://jsfiddle.net/8BQv5/).

Comment: Thank you! I tried what you did in the fiddle, and the hovering and clicking both work; however the radius of 0 creates a new problem with my project (highlighting points). I will create a new question if I cannot figure it out, as it is a different matter, and I will post a link on here if you would like to take a look.

Comment: I was able to make adjustments to the jquery.flot.js source code to account for the 0 radius with the drawPointHighlight method. Thank you for everything!

Comment: I was able to keep the hover effect by adding `lines:{show: true, lineWidth: 0}` and changing points to show false. I will test in windows firefox, and let you know the results of that as well.