# Is jquery.flot.dashes.js compatible with windows firefox?

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox, plugins, flot

I am using jquery.flot.dashes.js to graph in black and white and still have distinguishable series. Although a problem with firefox on windows results with this display:

[image]

When the expected outcome is this:

[image]

Is there a compatibility issue between jquery.flot.dashes.js and windows firefox? The plot works correctly on mac with firefox, chrome, safari, and opera. Of the windows browsers tested, the plot does not work on firefox with windows 7 or windows 8.1 professional (I don't have the software to test vista or 8). The plot worked on windows 7 with chrome (didn't test IE). The plot worked on windows 8.1 professional with chrome and IE. What could the source of this display issue be? Is there an available patch for it?

Link to jquery.flot.dashes.js source code:

https://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/attachmentText?id=61&aid=-4351874625254130968&name=jquery.flot.dashes.js&token=30636c55acd3aa96d9850f8d77953384

Other scripts being used:

jquery.flot.js
jquery.flot.selection.js
My own custom js file for graph-user interaction.

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, why do you provide the black and white option?  Is this for printing to non-color devices or do you have color blind users?  I  once worked on a project where both of our leads were color blind, we had a hell of a time presenting visualizations to them...

Comment: Both color blind users and printing purposes are the reasons for black and white option. The plot is intended for a student eBook, so we have to make it usable for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue with the latest Firefox version 31.0 (it was not present with my previous version 30.0). So it looks like Firefox is the cause of the problem. But the problem is not with flot.dashes, but with the basic flot:

When you "draw" points with `radius: 0` as described in the answer to [your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593077/does-jquery-flot-dashes-js-support-plothover-and-plotclick), Firefox draws points with what seems like `radius: 1` in addition to the dashed line. This leads to the result you get in your image.

I have not yet found a way how to prevent this. For the time being you could try the other solution from Mark's answer to your other question (modifiing jquery.flot.js).

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into modifying jquery.flot.js.

Comment: Changing points to show false and making the adjustment `lines:{show: true, lineWidth: 0}` solved the display issue and maintained hover ability.